# Configure Kafka-indexing-service in Druid

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, druid

After installing Druid i want to connect with Kafka. So, in my Apache Druid i came up with this information:

[image]

After i follow the instructions my file located at /opt/druid/conf/druid/cluster/_common/common.runtime.properties had already the extension as you can see on the following picture:

[image]

Apache Druid: 0.21.1
Apache Kafka: latest

I am doing this using docker. Both are installed on the same machine.
After everything an following all the information in documentation i am not able to connect Kafka and Druid because i am still getting the message:  "please make sure that kafka-indexing-service extension is included in the loadlist" in Druid

Update:

My Docker Composer:

```
version: '2'
services:
  spark:
    container_name: spark
    image: bde2020/spark-master
    ports: 
      - 9180:8080
      - 9177:7077
      - 9181:8081
    links: 
      - elassandra
    volumes:
hosein:/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/python
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra/mostafa-hosein:/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/python



  elassandra:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    container_name: elassandra
    build: /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra
    env_file:
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra/conf/cassandra.env
    volumes:
      - /home/mostafa/Desktop/kafka-test/together/cassandra/jarfile:/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '7001:7001'
      - '7199:7199'
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9142:9142'
      - '9160:9160'
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    build: .
    container_name: kafka
    links:
     - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=7071:/usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
      CONNECTORS: elassandra
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on: 
      - elassandra

  kafka_connect-cassandra:
    image: datamountaineer/kafka-connect-cassandra
    container_name: kafka-connect-cassandra
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
      - 9102:9102
    environment: 
      - connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT =  "zookeeper:2181"
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS= "kafka:9092"
      - connect.cassandra.port=9042
      - connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
      - tasks.max=1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - elassandra
```

Druid Config: (conf/druid/cluster/_common/common.runtime.properties)

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Extensions specified in the load list will be loaded by Druid
# We are using local fs for deep storage - not recommended for production - use S3, HDFS, or NFS instead
# We are using local derby for the metadata store - not recommended for production - use MySQL or Postgres instead

# If you specify `druid.extensions.loadList=[]`, Druid won't load any extension from file system.
# If you don't specify `druid.extensions.loadList`, Druid will load all the extensions under root extension directory.
# More info: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/including-extensions.html
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-hdfs-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "druid-datasketches"]

# If you have a different version of Hadoop, place your Hadoop client jar files in your hadoop-dependencies directory
# and uncomment the line below to point to your directory.
#druid.extensions.hadoopDependenciesDir=/my/dir/hadoop-dependencies


#
# Hostname
#
druid.host=localhost

#
# Logging
#

# Log all runtime properties on startup. Disable to avoid logging properties on startup:
druid.startup.logging.logProperties=true
#
# Zookeeper
#

druid.zk.service.host=localhost
druid.zk.paths.base=/druid

#
# Metadata storage
#

# For Derby server on your Druid Coordinator (only viable in a cluster with a single Coordinator, no fail-over):
druid.metadata.storage.type=derby
druid.metadata.storage.connector.connectURI=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/var/druid/metadata.db;create=true
druid.metadata.storage.connector.host=localhost
druid.metadata.storage.connector.port=1527

# For MySQL (make sure to include the MySQL JDBC driver on the classpath):
#druid.metadata.storage.type=mysql
#druid.metadata.storage.connector.connectURI=jdbc:mysql://db.example.com:3306/druid
#druid.metadata.storage.connector.user=...
#druid.metadata.storage.connector.password=...

# For PostgreSQL:
#druid.metadata.storage.type=postgresql
#druid.metadata.storage.connector.connectURI=jdbc:postgresql://db.example.com:5432/druid
#druid.metadata.storage.connector.user=...
#druid.metadata.storage.connector.password=...

#
# Deep storage
#

# For local disk (only viable in a cluster if this is a network mount):
druid.storage.type=local
druid.storage.storageDirectory=var/druid/segments

# For HDFS:
#druid.storage.type=hdfs
#druid.storage.storageDirectory=/druid/segments

# For S3:
#druid.storage.type=s3
#druid.storage.bucket=your-bucket
#druid.storage.baseKey=druid/segments
#druid.s3.accessKey=...
#druid.s3.secretKey=...
#
# Indexing service logs
#

# For local disk (only viable in a cluster if this is a network mount):
druid.indexer.logs.type=file
druid.indexer.logs.directory=var/druid/indexing-logs

# For HDFS:
#druid.indexer.logs.type=hdfs
#druid.indexer.logs.directory=/druid/indexing-logs

# For S3:
#druid.indexer.logs.type=s3
#druid.indexer.logs.s3Bucket=your-bucket
#druid.indexer.logs.s3Prefix=druid/indexing-logs

#
# Service discovery
#

druid.selectors.indexing.serviceName=druid/overlord
druid.selectors.coordinator.serviceName=druid/coordinator

#
# Monitoring
#

druid.monitoring.monitors=["org.apache.druid.java.util.metrics.JvmMonitor"]
druid.emitter=noop
druid.emitter.logging.logLevel=info

# Storage type of double columns
# ommiting this will lead to index double as float at the storage layer

druid.indexing.doubleStorage=double

#
# Security
#
druid.server.hiddenProperties=["druid.s3.accessKey","druid.s3.secretKey","druid.metadata.storage.connector.password"]


#
# SQL
#
druid.sql.enable=true

#
# Lookups
#
druid.lookup.enableLookupSyncOnStartup=false
```

Comment: Please show your specific properties as text, and specific errors you're getting

Comment: If druid is in Docker, then how is it reading your /opt conf file?

Comment: Hello,
My error is the same of the first picture "please make sure that kafka-indexing-service extension is included in the loadlist".
And, as you can see, i have kafka-indexing-service in loadlist. 
Thanks for helping !

Comment: Please edit your question to include your compose file or Docker run commands and your full druid config as text, not an image

Comment: Done Friend, hope you can help :)

Comment: 1) You should use `image: wurstmeister/kafka` if you're not modifiying anything in that container rather than building it 2) Have you verified that the Kafka container itself works using other tools from the host?

Comment: Yes, Kafka is working. I used that image but i can`t connect with Druid ...

Comment: And the error only happens when using Docker? Are you running any Druid components in Docker? Because I don't see it... If you follow the Druid Kafka quickstart page, it all works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the coordinator container, and Kafka will become available. Then, you can start it again.

Once you configure the Kafka settings, it will work normally.